# Segue Optional Value nil

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swift3

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let newuser = users[indexPath.row]
    let usernname = newuser.name! as String
    print(usernname)
    print(keys[indexPath.row])
    let destinationViewController = ChatViewController()
    destinationViewController.toUid = keys[indexPath.row]
    destinationViewController.topBar.title = usernname
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toChatView", sender: self)
}
```

keys[indexPath.row] is working correctly but username has error. It says

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

But when I print my `username` variable, It prints OK

Comment: where is your perform segue method?

Comment: try to use if let usernname = newuser.name! as String{ do code in if condition}

Comment: @Mr.UB Well, it's in my code

Answer (score 0):

you need to check if username is nil or not

```
let usernname = newuser.name! as String

let destinationViewController = ChatViewController()
destinationViewController.toUid = keys[indexPath.row]

if username != nil { // check if this is nil or not
 print(usernname)
 print(keys[indexPath.row])
 destinationViewController.topBar.title = usernname
 performSegue(withIdentifier: "toChatView", sender: self)
}
```